# Installing Debian but can't boot

Tags: boot, installation, debian, grub, efi

I'm installing Debian testing on a SSD, there is a pre-existing EFI ESP partition from windows installation, the disk uses GPT partitioning. Problem is after it finishes installing it won't boot linux or grub. In my motherboard UEFI boot order I see a japenese sign that appeared after the installation, when I try to boot on it it won't do anything. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Always select UEFI boot for USB or DVD when installing any new OS to hard disk or SSD. You could disable CSM in firmware to be sure to use only EFI boot.